# Is there any way to show a sheet tab when a Checkbox is true/ticked?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example, let's say we have a list of names of cars in Sheet1.

Each car has a checkbox next to it.

When the checkbox is ticked, is there any way of opening a tab that is related to that vehicle? (provided that all of the vehicle tabs are previously created but hidden when the checkboxes are false/unticked)

Comment: not really what you are looking for but might do what you want differently... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1smNwmb-DT4l54135QltGxnIwl-ESal9CxbkOTJNcPsc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can trigger a script when the cell is changed with the onEdit trigger, check if the value is checked/unchecked, determine which Sheet to show/hide, and use SpreadsheetApp to show or hide the relevant Sheet (tab).

Check the Trigger documentation, as well as the SpreadsheetApp documentation.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet